# Does it mean that any set can be inductive only and only if it contains positive integers?

Tags: induction

[image]

So according to the above explanation, any set can be inductive as long as it contains the positive integers? It means the set of rational numbers is inductive only and only because it contains all the positive integers. Also, in the definiton, that "$x$" has to be an integer or it can be any number in the given set?

What is the use of the inductive property of rational numbers? I know for the set of positive integers, PMI is the best example. But, what about rational numbers?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it says that any inductive set must include the positive integers.  It does not say that any set that includes the positive integers is inductive.  For example, $\{\frac 12\} \cup \Bbb N$ is not inductive because $\frac 12+1$ is not a member of the set.  Yes, the rationals are inductive because they are closed under addition of $1$.  Similarly, the integers are inductive.  The set of naturals union the naturals plus $\frac 13$ is also inductive.

Comment: One last doubt: I know what is the role of the inductive property of the set of natural numbers. But what does the inductive property of rational numbers do? Where is it used? Or they are just inductive?

Comment: That is a very different question.  Within the naturals, it allows us the last Peano axiom, that $(P(1)\wedge(\forall n P(n)\implies P(n+1))) \implies \forall n P(n)$ but that doesn't work for all inductive sets.

Comment: Alright, I think I am overthinking over this. I'll just stop here that they are just inductive.